# New type of auto-generated constructor in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

The code below doesn't compile on GCC 11 with `-std=c++17`, but does with `-std=c++20`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    std::string s;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo("hello", 42);
    std::cout << foo.s << ' ' << foo.i << '\n';
}
```

What's the feature in C++20 that enables this? What kind of constructor is generated by the compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++20 feature being used here is the [initialization of aggregates from parenthesis (P0960R3)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html):

> This paper proposes allowing initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values; that is, `Aggr(val1, val2)` would mean the same thing as `Aggr{val1, val2}`, except that narrowing conversions are allowed.

Here is an example from the above link:

```cpp
struct A {
  int a;
  int&& r;
};

int f();
int n = 10;

A a1{1, f()};               // OK, lifetime is extended
A a2(1, f());               // well-formed, but dangling reference
A a3{1.0, 1};               // error: narrowing conversion
A a4(1.0, 1);               // well-formed, but dangling reference
A a5(1.0, std::move(n));    // OK
```

So, for your code to work with C++17, just replace the parenthesis with braces.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    std::string s;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{"hello", 42};
    std::cout << foo.s << ' ' << foo.i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner. Why would it be a dangling reference in `a2` and `a4`.

Comment: @Ｎａｒｕｔｏ: The reason behind that is really complicated (FWIW, I would have to look it up in the standard, so it's not obvious even for an expert), so it's best not to know. Just avoid using references in your aggregates like this.

Comment: @Ｎａｒｕｔｏ If you go the same link, you would see this: "A *temporary bound to a reference member of the aggregate via braces has its lifetime extended*, whereas *no extension happens when the temporary is passed via round parentheses*." So, in cases of `a2` and `a4`, the temporaries get destroyed but the references still remain intact but as they refer to deleted objects, they become *dangling*.

Comment: fyi Aggregate initialization has changed / keeps changing and is something I try to avoid currently (want to see if it stabilises) see (and note the number of C++XX notes) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization